# No variants found for ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i'm trying to prepare a flutter project for upload, i'am using android studio but it gives me this error when i try to build it.

No variants found for ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.

I tried flutter downgrade and tried to change the gre.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.